# fade_in fade_out to call another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to use fade_in fade_out of Jquery to display a form from another form page :
for example, the current page displays a form with : Name , Age, Country. I am using autocompletion for the "Country" input. So if a use doesn't find his country with autocompletion, he should add it without changing the page. So i'd like to call another page containing a form that adds a country, with the fade_in effect.

How can i di this? thanks

Comment: you need to use ajax and read some basic tutos

Comment: No need to call another page. You can keep a hidden input box and then show it when the user does not find the required country name.

Comment: @Ahmed : this is easier in php, but not in rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer

**CODE**

**HTML**

```
<div class="p1"><input type="text" placeholder="Name" /><br /><input type="text" placeholder="Address" /><br /><select id="country" ><option>Select a country</option><option value="india">India</option><option value="add">Add new country</option></select>
  <input  type="button" id="subc" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.p1 { padding:10px; text-align:center }
.p2 { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; width:100%; text-align:center; background-color:#FFF; display:none }
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#country').change(function(e) {
        if($(this).val() == 'add'){
            $('.p1').fadeOut()
            $('.p2').fadeIn()
        }
    });
    $('#addc').click(function(e) {
        $c = $('#ncountry').val()
        if($c != ''){
        $('#country').append('<option>'+$c+'</option>')
        alert('Country added to list')
        $('.p2').fadeOut()
            $('.p1').fadeIn()
        }
        else{
            alert('Enter a country name')
        }
    });
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krunalp1993/tkBDN/1/

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: thanks! but how can i make the display in the same windown with a fade in animation : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=631755ajaxtag.png (like this)

Comment: brilliant! what did you change?